# How to detect if the A,S,D or/and W button is pressed in cocos2d-mac?

Tags: macos, cocos2d-iphone, key, move, detect

I want to move my ccsprite/b2body with the <kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd> keys in **cocos2d for mac**. How can I detect if one of these buttons are pressed? Can the user press multiplie keys at simultaneous? Can cocos2d for mac handle multiplie keys when they are pressed?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

- [Cocos2d handling events](http://cocos2d.org/doc/programming_guide/handling_events.html) (it detects none, one, or several keys pressed at the same time)
- [Find Key Codes For Your Mac Keyboard](http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2008/07/find-key-codes-for-your-mac-keyboard.html)